# fields_for - loading all records in the has many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add some new Tasks to my Project.   The Project currently has over 1000 Tasks.

When I use fields_for

```
=form_for @project do |f|
  =f.fields_for :tasks, @project.tasks.build do |task_fields|
    =task_fields.text_field :name
```

It seems to load all of the associated Tasks even though the form is only for one new Tasks.  Is this how fields_for should behave or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
  =f.fields_for :tasks, @project.tasks.build do |task_fields|
```

with:

```
  =f.fields_for :tasks, [@project.tasks.build] do |task_fields|
```

This is the one-to-many relation, so you have to provide many (ie: an array) objects. The `[obj]` makes it for you.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this how fields_for should behave or am I missing something?

If you're using fields_for and accepts_nested_attributes_for etc. then, yes this is how it's supposed to behave.  This paradigm is primarily used for when you'd be adding/editing both (project and task objects) at the same time.

If you just want to add one task at a time, I'd recommend just creating a task MVC and then nest it under the project resource.  In other words, by nesting it (i.e. ../projects/2/tasks/new), you'd always have a project in context. The only caveat here is you'd have to have an existing project to add the task (unlike the fields_for paradigm above).

If you're not already familiar with nested resources, these [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) will help.